# XML file creation using PHP

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML formatting is not working well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859050/xml-formatting-is-not-working-well)

I am trying to create an XML file from the database.  Database contains name, phone no and sex.  I would like to get all the users' details in a well-formatted XML file.  But I am getting now:

```
<CUSTOMERS>
    <name>AAA</name>
    <name>BBB</name>
</CUSTOMERS>
```

This is my code:

```
$xmlstr = "<?xml version='1.0' ?>\n"."<CUSTOMERS></CUSTOMERS>";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
while($b=$result->fetch_assoc()){

$xml->addChild("name", $b['name']);

}
return $xml->asXML();
```

I would like to get the out put as shows below

```
<CUSTOMERS>
<AAAA>
<name>AAA</name>
<phone>111</phone>
<sex>male</sex>
</AAA>
<BBBB>
<name>BBB</name>
<phone>222</phone>
<sex>female</sex>
</AAA>
</CUSTOMERS>
```

---

Latest Code

```
        $xmlstr = "<?xml version='1.0' ?>\n"."<CUSTOMERS></CUSTOMERS>";
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

        while($b=$result->fetch_assoc()){


            $customer = $xml->addChild("customer");
            $customer->addChild("name", $b['name']);
            $customer->addChild("phone", $b['phone']);
            $customer->addChild("sex", $b['sex']);
            //$xml->addChild("place", $b['place']);
        }
        return $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I would like make an xam contain  user name,phone no and sex from database. But now in my xml file Iam getting only the names of all the users. I would like create an xml file including the 3 fields(foreach user). Thanks

Comment: All three answers given to your question are technically correct; it seems that you're using the output for something else and it fails there, so please specify what you're using it for (add code).

Comment: Could it be the \n character which passed to the SimpleXMLElement constructor be the problem? I guess it is interpreted as an invalid XML element and it is on line 2.

Answer (score 1):

Each customer should be in its own tag:

```
$d = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><customers />');

$customer = $d->addChild('customer');
$customer->addChild('name', 'Jack');
// $customer->addChild('phone', '911');
// etc.
$customer = $d->addChild('customer');
$customer->addChild('name', 'John');

echo $d->asXML();

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customers>
  <customer><name>Jack</name></customer>
  <customer><name>John</name></customer>
</customers>
```

Note that the tag name should not be the name of your customer, it should rather be a description of what information is inside; hence my use of the `customer` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<customers></customers>");
while($b=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $customer = $xml->addChild("customer");
    $customer->addChild("name", $b['name']);
    $customer->addChild("phone", $b['phone']);
    $customer->addChild("sex", $b['sex']);
}
```

Output:

```
<customers>
    <customer>
        <name>AAA</name>
        <phone>1234567</phone>
        <sex>f</sex>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

Comment: But this code generates an error as " XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 2: Invalid document end"

Comment: @user1431849 Please see update-- the constructor for *SimpleXMLElement* should be a bit different.

Comment: Same error now "XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 2: Invalid document end"

Comment: @user1431849 I just prototyped it, and it works for me using *echo*.  Maybe you could post some more of your code that shows how you're returning the result?

Answer (score 0):

You are telling PHP to add the `<name>` child but nothing else.

```
$xml->addChild("name", $b['name']);
```

In that while loop, you need to add the `<AAA>` element, then the child `<name>`, `<phone>`, and `<sex>` (and etc) elements.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Could u make it clear.

Comment: I can't really make it any more clear. You're not adding all of the elements you want to add. So... add them.

Comment: I have updated the code. But still it shows an error as"XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 2: Invalid document end'

Comment: We don't know what's on line 2. Consider posting the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The question is to change this

```
$xmlstr = "<?xml version='1.0' ?>\n"."<CUSTOMERS></CUSTOMERS>";
```

to this

```
$xmlstr = = '<' . '?xml version='1.0' ?>\n"."<CUSTOMERS></CUSTOMERS>';
```

As the `<?` messes up the parser.

Also XML does not like capitals and needs a root - i.e. something between your customers.

Comment: XML is OK with capitals.  Perhaps you are confusing XML and HTML.  (The latter is case insensitive.)